# I can't figure out how to get the right output in Python

Tags: python

To put it simply, my input is:

```
capitalize_me = ['an abacus','bitter beefsteak','comfy culottes']
for i in capitalize_me: 
    print(i.capitalize(), end=',')
```

and my output is: `An abacus,Bitter beefsteak,Comfy culottes,`

But I need: `[An abacus,Bitter beefsteak,Comfy culottes,]` with the brackets. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: append it to a list in the loop and print at the end?

Comment: Use a list comprehension instead of a loop.

Comment: Note that if you get the brackets you'll also get quotes.

Comment: Do you really need a `,` at the end of the list?

Answer (score 1):

You never stored the converted strings back into a list.

```
capitalize_me = ['an abacus','bitter beefsteak','comfy culottes']

done = [phrase.capitalize() for phrase in capitalize_me ]

print(done)
```